# setCurrentDrive? c++ win32

Tags: c++, winapi, drive

How can I set the current drive in c++?  I was unable to find anything on the MSDN site

Comment: Do you have any code?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I think it would be good to detail what is the context that you want to "change the drive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you use to set the directory can be prefixed by the drive letter -- i.e., "c:\program files".

Directories are set relative to your programs current working directory. If you start your program from 'X' drive you will not be able to move outside of 'X' using relative conventions/directory addressing. You need to use a directory string prefixed with the correct drive letter.

Comment: so if I run the program from drive X
I should be able to do this?
setCurrentDirectory("Y:/test");
?

Comment: With a backslash, yes. The doc mentions you should have a trailing backslash too.

Comment: It DOES! work!... thanks guys, I had tried it befor but didn't debug correctly  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to thr MSDN docs on the Win API, `SetCurrentDirectory` will also set the current drive.